# The best tts recommendation

Tags: python, speech-synthesis

I am working on a project in python where I need to use text-to-speech. The problem is all the tts libraries I found do not really sound natural like **gTTS** and **pyttsx3**.  They all kind of suck for what I'm trying to do.

I want a way to implement **tts** in my project that sounds natural and human-like but is still free and easy to implement.